# How to minimize code based on selector in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

jQuery script code:

```
$(function() {
   $('#html_btn1').change(function(){

        var val = $(this).val();
        switch(val.substring(val.lastIndexOf('.')+1).toLowerCase()){
        case 'jpg' : 
        case 'png' :
        case 'gif' :
        case 'jpeg' : showimagepreview1(this); break;
        default : $('#errorimg').html("Invalid Photo"); break;
        }

    });

    $('#html_btn2').change(function(){

        var val = $(this).val();
        switch(val.substring(val.lastIndexOf('.')+1).toLowerCase()){
        case 'jpg' : 
        case 'png' :
        case 'gif' :
        case 'jpeg' : showimagepreview2(this); break;
        default : $('#errorimg').html("Invalid Photo"); break;
        }

    });

    $('#html_btn3').change(function(){

        var val = $(this).val();
        switch(val.substring(val.lastIndexOf('.')+1).toLowerCase()){
        case 'jpg' : 
        case 'png' :
        case 'gif' :
        case 'jpeg' : showimagepreview3(this); break;
        default : $('#errorimg').html("Invalid Photo"); break;
        }
    });

    function showimagepreview1(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var filerdr = new FileReader();
            filerdr.onload = function(e) {
                $('#cu1').attr('src', e.target.result);
            };
            filerdr.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

    function showimagepreview2(input) {

        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var filerdr = new FileReader();
            filerdr.onload = function(e) {
                $('#cu2').attr('src', e.target.result);
            };
            filerdr.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

    function showimagepreview3(input) {

        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var filerdr = new FileReader();
            filerdr.onload = function(e) {
                $('#cu3').attr('src', e.target.result);
            };
            filerdr.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
});
```

HTML markup:

```
 <div class="form-group">
      <img id="cu1" src="upload-photo-img.jpg"/>
           <input type="file" path="images" id="html_btn1" />
     <img id="cu2" src="upload-photo-img.jpg"/>
           <input type="file" path="images" id="html_btn2" />
      <img id="cu3" src="upload-photo-img.jpg"/>
           <input type="file" path="images" id="html_btn3" />
 </div>
```

Above code works fine whenever I am trying to upload image it checks validate and preview the image

But I want to minimize my code as only one change function and only one showimagepreview function

Please give me an idea how to achieve?

Comment: This question should be moved to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Huangism is correct, this should probably be on codereview. But, for the sake of helping:

```
$(function() {
    // combine binding selector in to one
   $('#html_btn1,#html_btn2,#html_btn3').change(function(){

        var val = $(this).val();
        switch(val.substring(val.lastIndexOf('.')+1).toLowerCase()){
        case 'jpg' : 
        case 'png' :
        case 'gif' :
        case 'jpeg' : showimagepreview(this); break; // change to single "showimagepreview" function
        default : $('#errorimg').html("Invalid Photo"); break;
        }

    });

    function showimagepreview(input) {
        // grab "cu#" using the original element's id
        var cu_id = '#cu' + input.id.match(/\d+$/)[0];
        /* alt: var cu_id = input.id.replace('html_btn','#cu'); */

        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var filerdr = new FileReader();
            filerdr.onload = function(e) {
                // reference id here
                $(cu_id).attr('src', e.target.result);
            };
            filerdr.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);

        }
    }
});
```

1. Combine your bindings in to one using a comma-separated selector
2. Remove the duplicated `showimagepreview#` methods and unify into one function

   - Change hard-coded `cu#` ids in to a dynamic id based on the original input's ID.
   - Reference that id in the selector.

Answer (score 1):

Would it not be easier to use a class? As long as you are keeping the scope by using 'this'

You should be fine to have two generic functions like so

```
$('.addClassToImages').change(function(){

    var val = $(this).val();
    switch(val.substring(val.lastIndexOf('.')+1).toLowerCase()){
    case 'jpg' : 
    case 'png' :
    case 'gif' :
    case 'jpeg' : showimagepreview3(this); break;
    default : $('#errorimg').html("Invalid Photo"); break;
    }

});


function showimagepreview1(input) {
    var cu_id = '#cu' + input.id.match(/\d+$/)[0];

    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var filerdr = new FileReader();
        filerdr.onload = function(e) {
            $(cu_id).attr('src', e.target.result);
        };
        filerdr.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);

    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <img id="cu1" src="upload-photo-img.jpg"/>
       <input class="addClassToImages" type="file" path="images" id="html_btn1" />
 <img id="cu2" src="upload-photo-img.jpg"/>
       <input class="addClassToImages" type="file" path="images" id="html_btn2" />
  <img id="cu3" src="upload-photo-img.jpg"/>
       <input class="addClassToImages" type="file" path="images" id="html_btn3" />
 </div>
```

Comment: Made a mistake. if you combine the idea of adding classes and @Brad's showimagepreview function for dynamically matching the cu_id, you should get the results you want.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript:

```
    $(function() {
   $('input[type=file]').change(function(){
        var val = $(this).val();
        switch(val.substring(val.lastIndexOf('.')+1).toLowerCase()){
        case 'jpg' : 
        case 'png' : showimagepreview(this); break;
        case 'gif' :
        case 'jpeg' : showimagepreview(this); break;
        default : $('#errorimg').html("Invalid Photo"); break;
        }
    });

    function showimagepreview(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var filerdr = new FileReader();
            filerdr.onload = function(e) {
                $('#cu'+input.id).attr('src', e.target.result);
            };
            filerdr.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <img id="cu1" src="upload-photo-img.jpg"/>
       <input type="file" path="images" id="1" />
 <img id="cu2" src="upload-photo-img.jpg"/>
       <input type="file" path="images" id="2" />
  <img id="cu3" src="upload-photo-img.jpg"/>
       <input type="file" path="images" id="3" />
```

EDIT - UPDATED LINK
http://jsfiddle.net/S4mk2/

And... yes as Brad Christie mentioned, this would be ideal for HTML5

Comment: @Liquidchrome: Keep in mind, numeric-only IDs are only HTML5-friendly.